# How to display data on web page in real time from influxdb with node.js

Tags: node.js, influxdb

I am trying to make an application where an input value given is stored in influxdb and on other route i should display the values that stored in influxdb. The problem is i need to show the data on page real time but in my app i need to refresh the page to show the data newly added.

Is there any way that i can update the page in real time.

`/input` route that stores the value to db.

```
mqttClient.subscribe(topic, function() {
influxClient.write('sliderValue')
  .field({
    slider_value:value
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.info('write point success');
  })
  .catch(console.error);// message is Buffer
mqttClient.end();
});
```

`/output` route that displays the values from db

```
mqttClient.publish(topic, msg, function() {
  influxClient.query('sliderValue')
  .then((rows) => {
    res.render('output',{page_title:"Output",data:rows.results[0].series[0].values});

    res.end();
  }).catch(console.error);
});
```

I am not using any library like socket.io here as of now i am simply displaying the values:

```
html
head
    title= 'Output'
body
    h1= 'Slider List'
table
    for row in data
        tr
            td= row
```

Comment: Do you have any front-end code that you can share? You need something on the client to either poll, or create a socket connection if you want to get realtime data without refreshing.

Comment: Should i need to use some client library like socket.io

Comment: That's definitely a possibility if you're comfortable with that. You could also try polling with AJAX requests in a `setInterval` that hits your `/output` route.

Comment: https://socket.io/ probably use this ..

Comment: is it a good practice to just refresh with meta refresh tag as `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost:8080/output">`